# Small table with Link to more information

Tags: php, sql

This may be a newbie question,  But let's say I have a database table w/ 10 fields.  However, on the first screen I want a small 4-5 field table displaying corresponding data.  But the first field, let's call it ID, I want to be linkable to a full table that will display complete details about that, all 10 db fields.  What would the coding be...I have a friend that usually helps, but apparently this is too easy...he simply laughed at my question.  

Please help...thanks
Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this you're looking for?

First page:

```
<?php
// Create a connection above
$data = mysql_query('SELECT id, field2, field3, field4 FROM table') or die(mysql_error());
echo '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{
  echo '<tr><td><a href="info.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['id'] . '</td><td>'. $row['field1'] . '</td><td>'. $row['field2'] . '</td><td>'. $row['field3'] . '</td><td>'. $row['field4'] . '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

I am not sure what you want on the second page but if you want to display information about one specific row, you can do it in this way:

```
<?php
// Create a connection above
$data = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . '"') or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);    
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><td>Id:</td><td>' . $row['id'] . '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Field 1:</td><td>' . $row['field1'] . '</td></tr>';
// And so on...
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first page ought to have links like:

```
<a href="details.php?id=1023">Item 1023</a>
<a href="details.php?id=1024">Item 1024</a>
<a href="details.php?id=1025">Item 1025</a>
```

Which goes to `details.php`:

```
// Very simplified - DO NOT USE AS-IS
$id = $_GET["id"]; // perhaps has the value of '1024'
$details = getDetails($id); // queries db for all data for row having id = '1024'
```

And on `details.php` you can give the specifics.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Item Name</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Item Weight</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php print $details->name; ?></td>
      <td><?php print $details->weight; ?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What if the data for the small table is dynamically created from the database?  In that event the id= would need to be...something like id=$id right?  something like that....right?